# Emulator only got GCM messages?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have prepared one application for GCM with help of [GCM: Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html). It is working fine.I got messages in emulator.I have installed my app in device.when i send messages from server emulator only got the messages,but devices not getting messages.I think have done some mistake some where please guide me.

Comment: Did you register the device with GCM? Then did you send the Registration ID to server-side? What's the Result you get from sending request to GCM?

Comment: How to register the device with GCM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you register the device with GCM? 
for getting the Registration ID you have to do the Following code:

inside  onCreate() method, add the following code:

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
if (regId.equals("")) {
  GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
} else {
  Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
}
```

here you will get regId which you must have to sent it to the Server so that server can send push notification to Device which has the above regId.

for More Help you can refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html)

Answer (score 1):

check  GCMRegistrar log.
device can`t register in GCM , can`t got message
if success regist, you see device regId in log console.

or

check your 3rd party server or DB.