# Device is not getting the push notification whereas same code in emulator is getting the push notification using GCM

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-cloud-messaging

The application prepared by me is using GCM to get push notifications from the server.

The emulator is getting the push notification but my device is not getting the push notification when I install the same app on the device.

I have provided the SENDER_ID and API Key to the server. The registration Id and device id is sent through the code.

I am fetching the device id  using this code :

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager1 =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
device_id = telephonyManager1.getDeviceId();
```

I am stuck with the problem since last 2 days, but not able to solve it till now. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved as the problem was from the server side.

In GCM we do not need to provide the device id. But just the sender id, registration id and api key are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you register the device with GCM? for getting the Registration ID you have to do the Following code:

inside onCreate() method, add the following code:

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
if (regId.equals("")) {
  GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
} else {
  Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
}
```

here you will get regId which you must have to sent it to the Server so that server can send push notification to Device which has the above regId.

for More Help you can refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html)

**EDITED**

you can also refer this Link [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627428/emulator-only-got-gcm-messages)

Comment: Yes, I am getting the registration Id and I am sending it to the server to get the notification through onMessage().

Comment: Have you Give all the Permission in Manifest File as Described in official Link? Can you Post some more code that you can think may be causing a problem?

Comment: Yes, permissions are ok. But I have doubt on the device id. Is it the telephonyManager1.getDeviceId() or the Secure.ANDROID_ID that we should use.

Comment: hi all am register with device id in server.After registering the server am not getting any notification from the  server please help me.